# How many permutations of the letters TRIANGLE contain A, N and G not to be together ?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I've approached this by calculating $8!$ for the total permutations, and subtracting $6!$ (permutations that include ANG.)

$8! = 40320$
$6! = 720$

Thus, $8! - 6! = 39600$

Is this the correct approach?  The question is a little unclear as to whether ANG are not supposed to be together in order or at all.  If my interpretation is incorrect, how would I go about calculating this if ANG can't be together at all?

Comment: The question is indeed somewhat unclear. My interpretation is that the A, N, G are to be not together in any order. Then your $6!$ should be replaced by $3!6!$.

Comment: Please post the exact wording of the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig This is exactly how the question was worded.  (My teachers first language is not english, which probably explains it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that **none** of the $3$ specified letters are to be together.

- Remove $A,N,G$ temporarily.
- Permute the remaining $5$ letters  $\;\;\large\boxed.\quad\large\boxed.\quad\large\boxed.\quad\large\boxed.\quad\large\boxed.\;\;$ in $5!$ ways
- $\large\uparrow \large\boxed.\uparrow \large\boxed. \uparrow \large\boxed. \uparrow \large\boxed. \uparrow \large\boxed. \uparrow$
- Re insert the $3$ letters at any $3$ of the uparrows.
- Thus $5!\times 6\cdot 5\cdot4$